# Ruby on rails difference between Integration and Functional testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am wondering, if I use Integration testing, is functional testing necessary? And what about Acceptance testing? I am struggling to understand, if I can stick to Integration testing and then just forget about Functional testing?

Answer (score 14):

From the official Rails guide:

> In Rails, testing the **various actions of a controller** is a form of writing functional tests.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#functional-tests-for-your-controllers

> Integration tests are used to test how **various parts of our application** interact.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#integration-testing

Comment: It sounds weird as "functional" usually designate the highest level. I can not found these exact quotes in the current Rails guide, but indeed the idea is around...

Comment: Rails is very opinionated. It has its own namings.

Answer (score 3):

Quick answer: integration testing is essentially a subset of functional testing, and acceptance testing is a form of functional testing.

I recommend reading the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_testing) [articles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing) [on the subject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceptance_testing).  Keep in mind that the definitions of the various kinds of testing can be taken with a grain of salt.